# How To Access Subdirectory from Tests

Tags: python

I have a python project where I cannot run tests on a class in a subdirectory from the command line.   It works in Pycharm, but not from the command line.  I simplified it to the following:

```
/utils
  __init__.py
  util.py

/tests
  test.py
```

Where util.py looks like:

```
class UtilClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print(" in __init__ ")
```

And `utils/__init__.py` is:

```
from .util import (
    UtilClass
)
```

And test.py just tries to call it:

```
from utils import UtilClass
x = UtilClass()
```

When I run (from the top level directory):   `% python tests/test.py` is says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`.  Do I need to do something with the path to include utils?  Or some sort of init.py in the top level dir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that python does not include the current directory in the path when you do `% python tests/test.py`.  If you add 'import sys;print(sys.path)' to the beginning of test.py, you will see that the 'tests/' directory is part of the path, but the top level directory where you ran the command from is not there.  A couple of solutions:

**Option 1:  Add Current Directory Explicitly (temporary)**

Do `PYTHONPATH='.' python tests/test.py`.  If you do that, the top level directory will be in the path, so test.py will find utils/ and can find UtilClass.  This is purely temporary, so good for running tests.

You could also do `export PYTHONPATH='/path/to/top/level'` and it will stick around for the lifetime of that command line.

**Option 2:  Install Current Directory (lasts)**

Do `pip install -e .` from the top level directory.  This will install the directory as '--editable', intended for developing modules, which means that it creates a link to your development area.  Since its now installed, python will find it.  This will stick around until you uninstall it.